# SLI with Kubuntu 15.04 and twin Nvidia 970

Tags: nvidia, kde

Have successfully installed nvidia 346 driver for 970 GPU.  Using Kubuntu 15.04 and twin 970's.

What is the procedure to bring up SLI?

For that matter, how do I ask the computer to tell me if it's using only one or both?